# How to get video duration using YouTube API?

Tags: php, xml, api, youtube-api

I want to get the duration of a Youtube video. Here's the code I tried:

```
$vidID="voNEBqRZmBc";
//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voNEBqRZmBc
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $vidID;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($url);
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Please check the XML file. I got the title of this video. I want to get duration from `<yt:duration seconds='29'/>`.

How to get the `seconds` attribute this `<yt>` tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Due to the upcoming deprecation of the YouTube v2 API, here is an updated solution.

1. Start by cloning the Google API PHP Client [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
2. Next, you'll want to register an application with Google [here](https://cloud.google.com/console) by creating a new Project, turning on the YouTube Data API under the "APIs and auth → API" section, and
3. Create a new OAuth Client ID under "APIs and auth → Credentials" and add the full path to your redirect URI list. (i.e. http://example.com/get_youtube_duration.php)
4. Use [this](https://gist.github.com/chrisrasco/fc20d24473030417a155) code (which was adapted from [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#updating_a_video_by_adding_new_tags) sample code), while making sure to fill in the $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID and $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET variables with your own values from step 3.
5. Hardcode a value for the $videoId variable or set it using the video_id get parameter (i.e. http://example.com/get_youtube_duration.php?video_id=XXXXXXX)
6. Visit your script, click the link to authorize the app and use your google account to get a token, which redirects you back to your code and will display the duration.

Here is your output:

```
Video Duration

0 mins

29 secs
```

Some additional resources:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

### The following works for the V2 API only.

This worked for me based on the assumption that there is only one duration element in the feed.

```
<?php

$vidID="voNEBqRZmBc";
//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voNEBqRZmBc
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $vidID;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($url);
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$duration = $doc->getElementsByTagName('duration')->item(0)->getAttribute('seconds');

print "TITLE: ".$title."<br />";
print "Duration: ".$duration ."<br />";
```

Output:

```
TITLE: Introducing iTime
Duration: 29
```

Comment: This will stop working after API 2 deprecation on April 2015. Do you know an alternative solution?

Comment: Hi Daniele - Off hand I don't, but I'll take a look at it and see what I can find out.

Comment: @DanieleB I've updated my answer. I didn't dig into how to auth without user interaction with a browser, but the above code works with the new api.

Answer (score 11):

Here it is YouTube API V3, with example of getting video duration, but do not forget to create your API key at https://console.developers.google.com/project

```
     $vidkey = "cHPMH2sa2Q" ; video key for example 
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ;
$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
$VidDuration =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($VidDuration['items'] as $vidTime) 
{
$VidDuration= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alaa Sadik for your answer. :)

Comment: The Duration Seems not in correct format.

Answer (score 3):

A short and simple solution using SimpleXML:

```
function getYouTubeVideoDuration($id) {
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$id);
 return strval($xml->xpath('//yt:duration[@seconds]')[0]->attributes()->seconds);
}
```

Comment: @Pat: Here you go: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ttfsag

Comment: thanks ...oh! i just got rick rolled! i didn't know people still did that haha thanks, i needed a good laugh.

Comment: is gdata api still working?

Comment: I don't think this still works.

Answer (score 2):

All the prev answers provide the duration in a text format:

This solution will give you the hours / minutes / seconds for you to transform to whatever format you would like:

```
function getDurationInSeconds($talkId){
   $vidkey = $talkId;
   $apikey = "xxxxx";
   $dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
   $VidDuration =json_decode($dur, true);
   foreach ($VidDuration['items'] as $vidTime)
   {
       $VidDuration= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
   }
   preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $VidDuration, $parts);
   $hours = intval(floor($parts[0][0]/60) * 60 * 60);
   $minutes = intval($parts[0][0]%60 * 60);
   $seconds = intval($parts[0][1]);
   $totalSec = $hours + $minutes + $seconds; // This is the example in seconds
   return $totalSec;
}
```

Comment: How about `duration: "PT26M"`

Comment: How about PT1H21S?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy

```
function getYoutubeDuration($videoid) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $videoid . '?v=2');
      $result = $xml->xpath('//yt:duration[@seconds]');
      $total_seconds = (int) $result[0]->attributes()->seconds;

      return $total_seconds;
}

//now call this pretty function. As parameter I gave a video id to my function and bam!
echo getYoutubeDuration("y5nKxHn4yVA");
```

Comment: is gdata api still working?

Answer (score -2):

You can also get the duration in JSON

```
       $video_id = "<VIDEO_ID>";
       http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$video_id?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

Oh! Sorry you can get it by:

```
$duration = $xml->getElementsByTagName('duration')->item(0)->getAttribute('seconds');
```

Comment: Please read my question again.

Comment: is gdata api still working ?

Comment: @Nimrod007 no is not